create a random password store it in Azure key vault and use it in a bicep deployment
I have got a working bicep deployment script which creates resources such a sql server databases, virtual machines etc in an idempotent manner after several deployment test runs, dropping and creating the resources several times. However the problem with the script is this, I have hardcoded the credentials within the bicep parameter file, I am looking to improve this by removing the credentials and having it generated by the deployment, stored in key vault and then retried from key vault during deployment.
This means that key vault controls the secret which is what I want to achieve, I do not want to be the one controlling the secret.
I have got a PowerShell code snippet that will generate a random password
-Join("ABCDabcd&@#$%941GHSdf1414>9fDFG1^(1AA".tochararray() | Get-Random -Count 12 | % {[char]$_})
what I am struggling with is havingputting together a bicep code that will get the output of the snippet above or any other similar solution, storing it within key vault and either outputing the secret detail so that it can be used elsewhere in the code.
I have come across this
However I have doubts with this approach, if the deployment is executed 100 times, it will generate a password with 100 versions in key vault especially during deployment testing.
Perhaps another way would be to check if the secret exists first, if it does do not generate a new secret.
I find it easier to write a Powershell script to tackle this problem, but doing so creates a problem from a bicep IaC perspective, the key vault needs to be created by bicep.
Any thoughts on how to tackle this issue?

are you orchestrating your deployment through pipelines (i.e.: azure devops, github action, jenkis, octopus etc.) ? Saying that you dont have to do everything in bicep

Bicep also support user defined function but not sure that would work in your case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/user-defined-functions ?

You can follow below pattern, Just a demonstration code, not really been tested at my side.
1_keyvault.bicep
@description('Specifies the name of the key vault.')
param keyVaultName string

@description('Specifies the Azure location where the key vault should be created.')
param location string

@description('Specifies whether Azure Virtual Machines are permitted to retrieve certificates stored as secrets from the key vault.')
param enabledForDeployment bool = false

@description('Specifies whether Azure Disk Encryption is permitted to retrieve secrets from the vault and unwrap keys.')
param enabledForDiskEncryption bool = false

@description('Specifies whether Azure Resource Manager is permitted to retrieve secrets from the key vault.')
param enabledForTemplateDeployment bool = false

@description('Specifies the Azure Active Directory tenant ID that should be used for authenticating requests to the key vault. Get it by using Get-AzSubscription cmdlet.')
param tenantId string = subscription().tenantId

@description('Specifies the object ID of a user, service principal or security group in the Azure Active Directory tenant for the vault. The object ID must be unique for the list of access policies. Get it by using Get-AzADUser or Get-AzADServicePrincipal cmdlets.')
param objectId string

@description('Specifies the permissions to keys in the vault. Valid values are: all, encrypt, decrypt, wrapKey, unwrapKey, sign, verify, get, list, create, update, import, delete, backup, restore, recover, and purge.')
param keysPermissions array = [
  'list'
]

@description('Specifies the permissions to secrets in the vault. Valid values are: all, get, list, set, delete, backup, restore, recover, and purge.')
param secretsPermissions array = [
  'list'
]

@description('Specifies whether the key vault is a standard vault or a premium vault.')
@allowed([
  'standard'
  'premium'
])
param skuName string = 'standard'

@description('Specifies the name of the secret that you want to create.')
param secretName string

@description('Specifies the value of the secret that you want to create.')
@secure()
param secretValue string

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    enabledForDeployment: enabledForDeployment
    enabledForDiskEncryption: enabledForDiskEncryption
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: enabledForTemplateDeployment
    tenantId: tenantId
    enableSoftDelete: true
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 90
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        objectId: objectId
        tenantId: tenantId
        permissions: {
          keys: keysPermissions
          secrets: secretsPermissions
        }
      }
    ]
    sku: {
      name: skuName
      family: 'A'
    }
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
    }
  }
}

resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: kv
  name: secretName
  properties: {
    value: secretValue
  }
}


1_sql.bicep
param sqlServerName string
param location string
param adminLogin string

@secure()
param adminPassword string

resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: adminLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: adminPassword
    version: '12.0'
  }
}


1_main.bicep
param sqlServerName string
param adminLogin string

param keyvaultName string
param secretName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location


resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: keyvaultName
}

module sqlModule '1_sql.bicep' = {
  name: 'sqlDeployment'
  params: {
    location: location
    adminLogin: adminLogin
    adminPassword: kv.getSecret(secretName)
    sqlServerName: sqlServerName
  }
}


deploy.ps1

$rgName = "xxx"
#
$keyVaultName = "xxx"
$location = "xxx"
$objectId = "xxx"
$secretName = "xxx"
$secretValue = -Join("ABCDabcd&@#$%941GHSdf1414>9fDFG1^(1AA".tochararray() | Get-Random -Count 12 | % {[char]$_})
## or using parameter or ENV variables to avoid hardcode

$paramObject_kv = @{
    keyVaultName = $keyVaultName
    location     = $location
    objectId     = $objectId
    secretName   = $secretName
    secretValue  = $secretValue
}

## 1. deploy keyvault 

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "keyvaultDeployment" -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile "1_keyvault.bicep" -TemplateParameterObject $paramObject_kv


## 2. deploy sql
$sqlServerName = "xxx"
$adminLogin = "xxx"

$paramObject_main = @{
    sqlServerName = $sqlServerName
    adminLogin    = $adminLogin
    keyvaultName  = $keyVaultName
    secretName    = $secretName
}

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "sqlDeployment" -ResourceGroupName $rgName -TemplateFile "1_main.bicep" -TemplateParameterObject $paramObject_main

